# The Lobatto quadrature formula

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus, quadrature

I have a problem with the computation of Lobatto quadrature formula.
In the second snippet of the Czech textbook they say:

we directly compute $(9.23)$ but I do not follow how did they computed $(9.25)$ and
$$A_i=\frac{\bar{A}_i}{1-x_i}^2, i=1,...,n-1$$

I think that  integral of $P_1(x)$ is $$-\frac{(1-x)^2}{4}f(-1)+\frac{(1+x)^2}{4}f(1)$$
and hence form $-1$ to $1$ is $f(-1)+f(1)$; what next, how do I compute $A_i$ in $(9.25)$ ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In 9.23 you insert some other quadrature method for the error of the trapezoidal method
$$
\int_{-1}^1(f(x)-P_1(x))\,dx=\int_{-1}^1 g(x)w(x)\,dx\approx\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\bar A_kg(x_k),\\~~~where~~~g(x)=\frac{f(x)-P_1(x)}{1-x^2},
$$
so that in total you get
$$
I(f)\approx f(-1)+f(1)+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\bar A_kg(x_k)
=f(-1)+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\bar A_k\frac{f(x_k)-P_1(x_k)}{1-x_k^2}+f(1),
$$
then separate the fraction with
$$
\frac{P_1(x_k)}{1-x_k^2}=\frac1{2(1+x_k)}f(-1)+\frac1{2(1-x_k)}f(1)
$$
and compare coefficients of $f(x_k)$, $k=0,...,n$ of the resulting expression with 9.25. Note that 9.25 is just a restatement of the target formula for $I(f)\approx Q(f)$.

Comment: You answer seems to be correct but a bit condensed, could you kindly elaborate on it;e.g. I do not follow how have you obtained $$=f(-1)+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\bar A_k\frac{f(x_k)-P_1(x_k)}{1-x_k^2},
$$ and **where** are the coefficients $f(x_k)$ how can I compare them ?

Comment: 1. I missed a term, of course $f(1)$ remains inside the formula. 2. for $k=1,...,n-1$ there is only one term with $f(x_k)$, for $f(\pm 1)$ there are multiple contributed by $P_1(x_k)$.

Comment: I do understand your "so that in total you get", but then I got stuck. Could you please make $\color{red}{red}$ what I have to compare $f(x_k)$ with ? Also, I do not follow your equation $$
\frac{P_1(x_k)}{1-x_k^2}=\frac1{2(1+x_k)}f(-1)+\frac1{2(1-x_k)}f(1)
$$

Comment: You collect the terms that have $f(x_k)$ in them and use that the coefficients of these terms sum up to the same on both sides of the equation. Leading to formulas for the $A_k$ like in the cited book.

Comment: But which equation ? Your "so that in total you get" is just rewritten $g(x_k)$ and that is clear. Now I have to compare $f(x_k)$ on both sides of *some* equation but I do not know which one. Also I still do not follow your  $$
\frac{P_1(x_k)}{1-x_k^2}=\frac1{2(1+x_k)}f(-1)+\frac1{2(1-x_k)}f(1).
$$ I just know that  $$(1+x_k)(1-x_k)=1-x_k^2.$$

Comment: $A_0=A_n$ should be $1$ in any case.

Comment: The middle terms contribute to $A_0$ and $A_n$. /// Look at the form of $P_1(x)$ to find these same factors.